# OpenXML escaping in constructor of Body element

Tags: vb.net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am instantiating an OpenXML body element using a string that looks like so (the structure is valid, part of it is omitted for readability:

**bodyString**:

```
<w:body>
   ...
   <w:customXml w:uri="http://www.cito.nl/citotester" w:element="xhtmlElementToOpenXml" xml:space="preserve">
     <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">replace words between &lt;&gt;</p>
   </w:customXml>
   <w:customXml w:uri="http://www.cito.nl/citotester" w:element="xhtmlElementToOpenXml" xml:space="preserve">
      <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">&lt;To be&gt;</p>
   </w:customXml>
   ...
</w:body>
```

Dim b as New Body(bodyString)
If I then read b.OuterXml the value is:

**b.OuterXml:**

```
<w:body>
   ...
   <w:customXml w:uri="x" w:element="y" xml:space="preserve">
     <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">replace words between &lt;&gt;</p>
   </w:customXml>
   <w:customXml w:uri="x" w:element="y" xml:space="preserve">
      <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><To be></p>
   </w:customXml>
   ...
</w:body>
```

The <  and >  in the first paragraph remain unchanged and those in the second paragraph are changed into the less/greater than symbols. This results in  an unclosed *To Be* element, and therefore invalid XML.

Anyone who knows a way to not have the escaped characters from the second paragraph changed?

EDIT: I created a issue in the project's GitHub so they are aware of this, as I also get the same problem: [Issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-Xml-PowerTools/issues/77)